# How can I check multiple variables and initialize the non-empty one?

Tags: php, html, variables, conditional-statements, isset

I have a form with multiple inputs for one value which have similar names. something like this:

```
isset($_GET['name1'])
isset($_GET['name2'])
isset($_GET['name3'])
```

Always, either only one of them is true or none of them. And here is my code:

```
$name = '';
if( isset($_GET['name1']) ){
    $name = $_GET['name1'];
} else if ( isset($_GET['name2']) ) {
    $name = $_GET['name2'];
} else if ( isset($_GET['name3']) ) {
    $name = $_GET['name3'];
}

echo $name;
```

My code works as well. But I guess I can do that without those conditions. Any idea how can I write that logic more clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    if (isset($_GET["name$i"])) {
        $name = $_GET["name$i"];
        break;
    }
}
```

Using the PHP 7 coalescing operator, you can write:

```
$name = $_GET["name1"] ?? $_GET["name2"] ?? $_GET["name3"] ?? "";
```

Comment: That's true. But I was looking for an approach using by `coalesce` function which is a new feature in PHP 7. Not sure what's that exactly, but I guess it checks the first value for null and if it is, then it investigates the next value and so on ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how to do it that doesn't necessarily bind you to only the name `name` + `1 through 3`.  The order of preference goes from left (most preferable) to right (least preferable), where preferable refers to the order we pick them in.

```
$names=['name1','name2','name3'];

$name = '';
foreach ($names as $value) {
  if (isset($_GET[$value])) {
    $name = $_GET[$value];
    break;
  }
}
echo $name;
```

Comment: He only wants the first non-empty name.

Comment: @mplungjan That's a fair point. *Naming* isn't the best there.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the `GET` array and test using `empty`

```
$name=false;
foreach( $_GET as $field => $value ){
    if( !empty( $value ) ) {
        $name=$value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could possibly use the ternary operator for this like below.

```
$name = $_GET['name1'] ?: $_GET['name2'] ?: $_GET['name3'] ?: '';
```

which should skip name1 and go to name2 if name1 is empty or isn't set